# Do you know a service that reports comments on AppStore and Android Market ?

Tags: app-store, google-play

I'm looking for a service that reports comments on my app on the AppStore and Android Market, so that I could read this each morning in 5 minutes.

Comments are the only way to be in touch with users (that reports crash and various issues) but it is so complicated that developpers rarely monitor it.

Does anyone know a tool ?